# Task exception was never retrieved, KeyError: 'activationCost' как исправить

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Если вкратце, по нажатию кнопки "Пополнить баланс" ничего не происходит, кнопка просто не реагирует на нажатие и выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                 
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling
_updates                                                                                                           
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):                     
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates 
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)                                                                            
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify             
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)                                                    
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update  
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)                                        
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify             
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)                                                    
  File "main.py", line 115, in pay                                                                                 
    await callback.message.edit_text('� Выберите метод оплаты:', reply_markup=ikb_payment)                         
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/types/message.py", line 2919, in edit_text              
    return await self.bot.edit_message_text(                                                                       
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 3122, in edit_message_text            
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.EDIT_MESSAGE_TEXT, payload)                                            
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request                      
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,        
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request                  
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())                     
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 115, in check_result                  
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)                                                                      
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 141, in detect               
    raise cls(description)                                                                                         
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: There is no text in the message to edit  

Ну а при нажатии кнопки выбора сервиса(любой страны) тоже ничего не происходит и появляется ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                 
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling
_updates                                                                                                           
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):                     
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates 
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)                                                                            
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify             
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)                                                    
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update  
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)                                        
  File "/home/BOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify             
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)                                                    
  File "main.py", line 275, in set_coontri                                                                         
    pricec = phone_number['activationCost']                                                                        
KeyError: 'activationCost'
```

Вот код:

````
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

from config import *
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from database import *
from keybord import *
from smsactivate.api import SMSActivateAPI
from country import *
import requests
from aiocryptopay import AioCryptoPay, Networks

cryptopay = AioCryptoPay(token=api_cryptobot, network=Networks.MAIN_NET)
sms = SMSActivateAPI(api_sms)

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def set_default_commands(dp):
    await dp.bot.set_my_commands([
        types.BotCommand("start", "Запустить бота")
    ])



async def RUB():
    data = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js').json()
    return round(float(data['Valute']['USD']['Value']), 2)

class CheksSub(BaseMiddleware):
    async def on_process_callback_query(self, callback: types.CallbackQuery, data: dict):
        db_start()
        if not user_exists(callback.from_user.id):
            add_users(callback.from_user.id)
        if await chec_shanel(channels=chanals, user=callback.from_user.id):

            pass
        else:
            await bot.delete_message(callback.from_user.id, callback.message.message_id)
            await callback.message.answer('<b>Для того, чтобы получить полный доступ , необходимо подписаться на канал </b>', reply_markup=show_canals())
            raise CancelHandler

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        db_start()
        if not user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            add_users(message.from_user.id)
        if await chec_shanel(channels=chanals, user=message.from_user.id):
            pass
        else:
            await message.answer('<b>Для того чтобы пользоваться нашим ботом, подпишитесь на каналы</b>',
                                          reply_markup=show_canals())
            raise CancelHandler




#Проверка подписки
async def chec_shanel(channels, user):
    for channal in channels:
        chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=channal[1], user_id=user)
        if chat_member['status'] == 'left':
            return False
    return True

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='stop_input', state='*')
async def stop_input(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await callback.message.answer('Вы вышли из режима ввода данных')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['Start'], state='*')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    if message.chat.type == 'private':

        db_start()

        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text='<b>Добро пожаловать в R.T.D SMS!</b>\n'
                                    '<b>Арендуйте анонимный или виртуальный номер в Telegram</b>\n'
                                    '❓<b>Есть вопросы? Свяжитесь с нашей поддержкой!</b>\n', reply_markup=kb, parse_mode='HTML')
        if not user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            add_users(message.from_user.id)




@dp.message_handler(text=' Мой профиль')
async def profile(message: types.Message):
    with open('/home/BOT/photo/profile.jpeg', 'rb') as photo:
        balance = chek_balance(message.from_user.id)
        await message.answer_photo(photo=types.InputFile(photo), caption=f' <b>Личный кабинет {message.from_user.first_name}</b>\n\n'
                             f' <b>ID:</b> <code>{message.from_user.id}</code>\n'
                            f'  <b>Баланс:</b> <code>{float(balance[0])}</code> Руб', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=ikb_money)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='back')
async def pay(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text(
                           text=' <b>Добро пожаловать в R.T.D SMS!</b>\n' ' <b>Арендуйте анонимный или виртуальный номер в Telegram с максимальным удобством.</b>\n' '❓ <b>Есть вопросы? Свяжитесь с нашей поддержкой!</b>\n', parse_mode='HTML')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='go_pay')
async def pay(callback: types.CallbackQuery):

    await callback.message.edit_text(' Выберите метод оплаты:', reply_markup=ikb_payment)

class User_pay(StatesGroup):
    amount = State()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='go_crypto')
async def pay(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text(' Укажите сумму пополнения.\n'
                                     ' Минимальная сумма пополнения: 0.1$.')
    await User_pay.amount.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=User_pay.amount)
async def fsm(message:types.Message, state:FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['amount'] = message.text

    invoce = await cryptopay.create_invoice(asset='USDT',
                                         amount=float(data['amount']),
                                         description='Пополнение баланса')


    await message.answer(f' Сумма к оплате: {data["amount"]}$\n'
                         f' Пополнять в USDT (TRC-20).', reply_markup=oplata_kb(id=invoce.invoice_id, url=invoce.bot_invoice_url, price=invoce.amount))
    await state.finish()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='check')
async def cheks(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    id_pay = callback.data.split('|')[1]
    amount = callback.data.split('|')[2]
    kurs = await RUB()
    res = int(kurs) * int(amount)

    invoce = await cryptopay.get_invoices('USDT', int(id_pay))

    if invoce.status != 'paid':
        await callback.answer('❌ Счет не оплачен!', show_alert=True)
    else:
        add_balances(callback.from_user.id, res)
        await callback.message.edit_text(f'Счет успешно оплачен, на баланс зачислено {res} Руб')
        await bot.send_message(ADMIN, f'Пользователь @{callback.from_user.username} успешно пополнил баланс на сумму {res}р')



@dp.callback_query_handler(text='done')
async def chek_subs(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.delete()
    if await chec_shanel(channels=chanals, user=callback.from_user.id):
        await callback.message.answer('<b>Добро пожаловать ❗️</b>', reply_markup=kb)




@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains ='next_c', state='*')
async def next_country(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    i = call.data.split('|')[1]

    await call.message.edit_text(text= '<b> Выберите страну:</b>', reply_markup=countryes(int(i)), parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(text='‍☠️Анонимные номера')
async def anonymous_numbers(message: types.Message):
    # Открываем файл с изображением
    with open('/home/BOT/photo/anon.jpeg', 'rb') as photo:
        # Отправляем сообщение с прикрепленным изображением и моноширинным текстом
        await message.answer_photo(
            photo=types.InputFile(photo),
            caption=(
                "<b>Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ваш запрос.</b>\n\n"
                "<b>На данный момент автоматическая выдача анонимных номеров недоступна.</b>"
                "<b>Тем не менее, вы можете приобрести их вручную через помощника.</b>\n\n"
                "<b>Не волнуйтесь, мы уже работаем над тем, чтобы сделать анонимные номера доступными автоматически как можно скорее.</b>\n\n"
                "<b>Спасибо за ваше понимание!</b> "
            ),
            reply_markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
                types.InlineKeyboardButton("Арендовать вручную", url="YOUR_USER_URL")
            ),
            parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML
        )

@dp.message_handler(text="Поддержка")
async def support_command(message: types.Message):
    # Отправка фото с кнопкой
    with open('/home/BOT/photo/support.jpeg', 'rb') as photo:
        await message.answer_photo(
            photo=types.InputFile(photo),
            reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
                InlineKeyboardButton(
                    'Написать поддержке',
                    url='YOUR_USER_URL'
                )
            )
        )

@dp.message_handler(text=' Виртуальные номера', state='*')
async def sms_go(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'<b> Выберите страну:</b>', reply_markup=countryes(0), parse_mode='HTML')



# @dp.message_handler(text=' Наши проекты', state='*')
# async def sms_go(message: types.Message):
#     await message.answer('')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='set_c|')
async def set_coontri(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state:FSMContext):
    strana = callback.data.split("|")[2]
    await callback.message.edit_text(f' <b>Страна:</b>{strana}\n'
                                     f' <b>Выберите сервис:</b>', reply_markup=service(0, strana=strana), parse_mode='HTML')




@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains ='next_s', state='*')
async def next_country(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    text = call['message']['text']
    text = ''.join(text)
    text = text.split('\n')[0]
    i = call.data.split('|')[1]
    text = text.split(':')[1]


    await call.message.edit_text(text=f' <b>Страна:</b>{text}\n Выберите сервис', reply_markup=service(int(i), strana=text), parse_mode='HTML')



@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='set_s_|')
async def set_coontri(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state:FSMContext):

    strana = callback.data.split('|')[3]

    kod_service = callback.data.split('|')[1]
    servise_kod = []
    for u, p in name_service.items():
        if p == int(kod_service):
            servise_kod.append(u)
    name = []
    for n, z in full_name.items():
        if n == int(kod_service):
            name.append(z)
    name = ''.join(name)

    kod_strana = []
    for m, s in COUNRTY.items():
        if s == strana:
            kod_strana.append(m)



    info = sms.getPrices(servise_kod[0], kod_strana[0])
    for q, r in info.items():

        cost = f'{q}:{r[servise_kod[0]]["cost"]}'
        counter = f'{q}:{r[servise_kod[0]]["count"]}'
        price  = cost.split(':')[1]
        count = counter.split(":")[1]


        phone_number = sms.getNumberV2(service=servise_kod[0], country=kod_strana[0])

        pricec = phone_number['activationCost']
        number_phone = phone_number['phoneNumber']
        result = float(pricec) + float(PRICE)


        if count == '0':
            await callback.answer('Номера закончились', show_alert=True)
        else:
            await callback.message.edit_text(f' <b>Страна:</b> {strana}\n'
                                         f' <b>Сервис:</b> {name}\n\n'
                                             f'☎ <b>Номер телефона:</b> <code>{number_phone}</code>\n'
                                             f'<b> Стоимость активации:</b> {float(result)} Руб.\n'
                                             f'<b> Доступное количество:</b> {count} шт\n'
                                             f'<b>⌛ Время активации:</b> 20 минут.\n\n'
                                             f'<b>Скопируйте номер телефона, вставьте его в ваш сервис для регистрации и нажмите   Получить код</b>' , parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup= await service_number(number_phone, phone_number['activationId'], int(result)))

        # await callback.answer('Номера закончились', show_alert=True)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='phone')
async def phone_go(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    price = callback.data.split('|')[3]
    id = callback.data.split('|')[2]
    number = callback.data.split('|')[1]
    phone_number = sms.getActiveActivations()
    print(phone_number['activeActivations'])
    for i in range(len(phone_number)):
        if phone_number['activeActivations'][i]['phoneNumber'] == number:
            sms_code = phone_number['activeActivations'][i]['smsCode']
            await callback.message.edit_text(f'Ваш смс код: <code>{sms_code}</code>\n'
                                             f'Номер телефона: <code>{number}</code>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=sms_replay(number, id, price))


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='go_sms')
async def phone_go(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    try:

        await callback.message.delete()
        price = callback.data.split('|')[3]
        id = callback.data.split('|')[2]
        number = callback.data.split('|')[1]
        phone_number = sms.getActiveActivations()
        for i in range(len(phone_number)):
            if phone_number['activeActivations'][i]['phoneNumber'] == number:
                sms_code = phone_number['activeActivations'][i]['smsCode']
                if sms_code == None:
                    await callback.message.answer(f'Ваш смс код: <code>{sms_code}</code>\n\n'
                                                  f'Номер телефона: <code>{number}</code>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=sms_replay(number, id, price))
                else:
                    await callback.message.answer(f'Ваш смс код: <code>{sms_code[0]}</code>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=sms_replay(number, id, price))
    except Exception:
        await callback.message.delete()
        price = callback.data.split('|')[3]
        number = callback.data.split('|')[1]
        id = callback.data.split('|')[2]
        phone_number = sms.getActiveActivations()
        for i in range(len(phone_number)):
            if phone_number['activeActivations'][0]['phoneNumber'] == number:
                sms_code = phone_number['activeActivations'][0]['smsCode']
                if sms_code == None:
                    await callback.message.answer(f'Ваш смс код: <code>{sms_code}</code>\n\n'
                                                  f'Номер телефона: <code>{number}</code>', parse_mode='HTML',
                                                  reply_markup=sms_replay(number, id))
                else:
                    await callback.message.answer(f'Ваш смс код: <code>{sms_code[0]}</code>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=sms_replay(number, id, price))


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='okay')
async def phone_go(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    price = callback.data.split('|')[3]
    number = callback.data.split('|')[1]
    id = callback.data.split('|')[2]
    status = sms.setStatus(id=id, forward=number, status=8)
    if status == 'EARLY_CANCEL_DENIED':
        await callback.answer('Нельзя отменить номер в первые 2 минуты', show_alert=True)
    else:
        await callback.message.edit_text('Активации успешно отменена')

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='nkay')
async def phone_go(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    price = callback.data.split('|')[3]
    number = callback.data.split('|')[1]
    id = callback.data.split('|')[2]
    status = sms.setStatus(id=id, forward=number, status=6)
    if status == 'ACCESS_ACTIVATION':
        await callback.message.edit_text('Сервис успешно активирован')
        minus_balance(callback.from_user.id, int(price))

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='not')
async def phone_go(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    price = callback.data.split('|')[3]
    number = callback.data.split('|')[1]
    id = callback.data.split('|')[2]
    status = sms.setStatus(id=id, forward=number, status=8)
    if status == 'ACCESS_CANCEL':
        await callback.message.edit_text('Активации успешно отменена')


async def on_startup(_):
    await set_default_commands(dp)
    print('Bot started')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.middleware.setup(CheksSub())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)```
````